# Ecommerce purchase value is not decreased after a refund event in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm migrating from UA to GA4 for ecommerce tracking.

I'm testing buy-and-refund scenario with GA: I sent a `purchase` event to GA4 via measurement protocal; After I ensured the `purchase` event is received (value showed in Ecommerce Purchases), I sent a `refund` event with the same transaction ID (through measurement protocal as well). I waited a day, but the value of purchase values in "GA4 Monetization -> Ecommerce Purchases" didn't decrease.

I'm sure the refund event is received (from Realtime report and Explore) by GA4. Is this a bug or expected behaviour? I didn't see it is described anywhere. Did I make any mistakes in event payload?

Here are my event payloads:

```json
          {
            "name": "purchase",
            "params": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "item_id": "L-6",
                        "item_name": "Product Report - 1775",
                        "item_category": "Report",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "price": 60,
                        "currency": "CNY"
                    }
                ],
                "currency": "CNY",
                "transaction_id": "LP-6",
                "value": 60
            }
```

```json
        {
            "name": "refund",
            "params": {
                "currency": "CNY",
                "transaction_id": "LP-6",
                "value": 60
            }
        }
```

When I was using UA, I could send negative revenue in `transaction` hit and negative quality in `transaction_item` hit in order to refund and decrease reveune. It seems this doesn't work in GA4? Should I should negative value in refund event? I didn't see any docs about it.

Comment: This question does not apear to be programming related. you may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is because you are not refunding the item in your snippet, only the transaction.
According to [Simo's article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-analytics-4-ecommerce-guide-google-tag-manager/#refund):

> Required parameters are transaction_id, and for each item that is
> refunded, item_id and quantity refunded.

Also in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm#refund) it says:

> Note: We recommend that you include item information in your refund event to see item-level refund metrics in Analytics.

So following your code, if you want to refund the item as well, it should be:

```
{"name": "refund",
  "params": {
  "currency": "CNY",
  "transaction_id": "LP-6",
  "value": 60,
  "items": [
    {
        "item_id": "L-6",
        "item_name": "Product Report - 1775",
        "item_category": "Report",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 60,
    }
]  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far my tests showed, GA4 just increments the metric "Refunds" by 1 after a full refund.

If you just need total number of purchases or E-commerce revenue, you could filter all the transactions that have refunds=0 and read the totals from "E-commerce revenue" or "E-commerce purchases", but I found that when you combine item-related dimensions or metrics (i.e. item name, item revenue, etc) the metric "Refunds" is showing as 0 even for refunded transactions.

Something is not quite right here.